# How do I show a path from one location to another location in react-native-maps?

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-native-maps

I am able to get the current GPS location and the GPS location of the place I want. But how do I set up a path between the 2 locations? I am able to put a marker on both location but I don't know how do I create a path between the 2 locations.

Here is my code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Button } from 'react-native'
import React , {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, onValue} from 'firebase/database'
import {db} from '../firebase'
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Loc from 'expo-location';


const Location = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey1
  console.log(paramKey)
  var lo, ke;
  const [todoDatak, setToDoDatak] = useState([])
  
  const [todoDatal, setToDoDatal] = useState([])
  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 1.3483,
    longitude: 103.6831,
    latitudeDelta: 0.005,
    longitudeDelta:0.0005,
  })
  const [mapRegionNow, setMapRegionNow] = useState({
    latitude: 1.3483,
    longitude: 103.6831,
    latitudeDelta: 0.005,
    longitudeDelta:0.0005,
  })
  const userLocation = async()=>{
    let { status } = await Loc.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      }
      let location = await Loc.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy:true});
      setMapRegionNow({
          latitude:location.coords.latitude,
          longitude:location.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta:0.005,
          longitudeDelta:0.0005,
      });
      console.log(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude)
  }

  
  useEffect (() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(db, "food/" + paramKey);
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) =>{
      
      ke = snapshot.key;
      setToDoDatak(ke)
      
      setToDoDatal(lo)
     
      });
      userLocation();
    }, [])
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
       
       <Text style = {styles.header}>Shop Name</Text>
       <Text style = {styles.text}>{todoDatak}</Text>
       
     
       <View style={styles.container}>
       
        <MapView style={styles.map} 
          region={mapRegion}
        >
          <Marker coordinate={mapRegionNow} title='MarkerNow'/>
          <Marker coordinate={mapRegion} title='Marker'/>
          </MapView>
          <Button title= 'Get Location' onPress={userLocation}/>
          
      </View> 
    </View>
    
  )
}

export default Location
```

`MapRegionNow` is for my existing location while `MapRegion` is the location that I need to get to

Comment: It looks like this is what you're looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps-directions Also try googling for "react-native-maps path" or "react-native-maps route". FYI Expo Location is for getting the current GPS position of the device, so it has nothing to do with maps or paths between locations. Because of that I edited the title of your question and added a `react-native-maps` tag